# Using equation $9x^2+8xy+7y^2=6$ to find maximum possible value of $7x+5y+12xy$.

Tags: inequality, polynomials

Can this problem be solved  cause I can't seem to figure it out.By analyzing the equation what I could only deduce was that either $x$ was negative or $y$ was negative OR $x$ and $y$ belonged in the interval $(0,1)$. If it is solvable how to solve it.And what led you to the conclusion it is possible to solve it.

Comment: Do you know how to do multivariable calculus? if so you'll know how to do the gradient.

Comment: I don't know multivariable calculus,but can't it be solved without using calculus?

Comment: oh I see, I was saying that it is possible to solve it with that method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given $6=7x^2+5y^2+2(x+y)^2+4xy$

From AM-GM inequality, $7x^2+\frac74\geqslant 7x,  \quad 5y^2+\frac54 \geqslant 5y, \quad 2(x+y)^2\geqslant 8xy$

Adding the three inequalities with the first equality, we have $6+\frac74+\frac54\geqslant 7x+5y+12xy$, and the maximum of $9$ is when the AM-GMs all have equality, i.e. when $x=y=\frac12$.

Comment: I know that AM>GM but can you explain what you did there at the second step

Comment: AM-GM inequality is exactly the second step - each of the three inequalities are AM-GM. Effectively this reduces the quadratic terms to linear ones, which is what we want. The last one can also be thought of as $(x-y)^2\ge0$, if that helps.

Comment: What i meant was how in  $7x^2+\frac74\geqslant 7x$ LHS is AM and RHS GM.

Comment: @Nobody An equivalent statement of AM-GM is $a^2+b^2\ge 2ab$. Divide both sides by $2$ and you have the means of $a^2,b^2$ in the form you seem to be familiar with.

Comment: Oh so the $7/4$ was added to make it in the form.Is that right?

Comment: Yes, no other number except $b^2=\frac74$ would work if we want $a^2=7x^2$ to become $2ab=7x$ on RHS.